# How do I determine which forms are using a particular VB6 user control?

Tags: forms, user-controls, vb6

I have a VB6.0 application in which I have forms and user controls. I need to know in which form a particular user control is being used. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean you need to do this at design-time or run-time?

Answer (score 3):

frm files are text files. Use an editor like Notepad++, [which is free](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), to search across all the files for the user control. You might want to add the user control to  a form, and then view the frm file in Notepad++, so that you know what to search for.

Here is the [manual topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241723%28VS.60%29.aspx) on frm format

Answer (score 0):

Object Browser -> Input UserControl classname and Find

Comment: This will work only if control instances are named UserControl1, UserControl2, etc. :-))